# Ubuntu 16.04 and Nvidia Prime: Pc does not shutdown

Tags: drivers, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have Ubuntu 16.04 installed together with the latest Nvidia drivers available from ppa:graphics-drivers.

If I restart/shutdown the computer, then it freezes on a black screen. This happens regardless of the videocard selected in the "Nvidia X Server Settings" -> "Nvidia PRIME Profiles".

The problem disappears if I disable the Intel integrated videocard in the bios settings. However in this case I cannot use the Nvidia Prime feature.

CPU: Intel i7-6700HQ
VGA: Nvidia 1060 (notebook)

Is this a known bug?

Comment: Could not find a clean solution, so I tried installing the SO again. I disabled the "boot from EFI" option in the BIOS and opted for a classic "AHCI". The problem did not appear again: my guess is that in EFI mode the nvidia graphic card was not correctly recognized, while in AHCI mode the card works just fine.